# http headers from one endpoint to other via AWS SNS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-sns

I have a requirement where I need to send some inbound http query parameters from api A by publishing it to SNS and other api B is subscribed to sns where it should get the query params.

Is there any way I can acheive it?

Note: I have a fixed message structure when I publish to SNS which I cannot change, since I have other endpoints who are already subscribing to SNS, depend on it.

As Michael mentioned, we can use lambda. but I do not want to use another service provided by aws. I want to acheive the same using SNS only. I heard about SNS message attributes, but not sure whether we can acheive the same using it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SNS doesn't support customizing the HTTP transaction or otherwise modifying the message being delivered... but SNS does support subscriptions that target a Lambda function.

This means you can write a Lambda function that parses the SNS event payload... and then, instead of SNS contacting the target system over HTTPS, your Lambda function makes the HTTPS request to the target endpoint, customized as required.  If the HTTPS request fails, or the endpoint returns an error, the Lambda function should throw an exception, so that Lambda can know to retry.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sns

Comment: Hi Michael, can you point me to a official documentation that says customizing the http headers is not possible, if there is any.

Comment: The SNS Developer Guide [documents the headers that are always provided](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-header) and there is no mention of customization... unless you are looking for basic or digest authentication via the `Authorization` header, which [is supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html).

Comment: Thanks for providing the lambda function option and pointing out the documents. I have heard about SNS message attributes. Can we use it somehow to send those query parameters with it to the endpoint api B?

Comment: The message attributes can be used for subscription filters, and they are included in the [event sent](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1VE917Z8J4UDY/Invoking-AWS-Lambda-functions-via-Amazon-SNS) to a Lambda subscription.  They do not appear to be included in the message sent directly to an HTTPS subscription.