# Adding a custom header to SNS Message

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm wondering if there is a way to add a custom header to an AWS SNS (Simple Notification Service) message.  It appears from reading the AWS documentation that all the headers included in SNS are defined by the SNS service, and you can not add your own.  Has anyone uncovered some way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as the documentation is concerned `SNS` doesnt allow changing the `Headers`

[HTTP/HTTPS headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-header)

There are multiple similar threads. For example:

[http headers from one endpoint to other via AWS SNS service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53082123/2246345)